# How to check whether multi value field is of type field_collection_item or not?

Tags: 7, entities

I am trying to check the type of multi value field is a `field_collection_item` or not inside computed field using this code:

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper($entity_type, $entity);  
$fields_info = $wrapper->getPropertyInfo();  
foreach ($fields_info as $req_field) {

  if ($req_field['type']=='field_collection_item') {  
    //do something here
  }
}
```

The `if` statement failed as `$req_field['type']` returns `list<field_collection_item>`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how an `EntityMetadataWrapper` stores multiple fields. There are only those two types, so just use

```
if($req_field['type'] == 'field_collection_item' || $req_field['type'] == 'list<field_collection_item>') {  
  // So something here
}
```

Or some variation on that.